# How to show hidden column when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, show-hide

I have a table, and I need hide/show the table column when click the header the column the column hide and the button will appear.when click the button i want to show the hidden coloumn How can I do this? 
see my code here http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/29/ .

Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $('table tbody tr:odd').addClass('alt');

    $('table tbody tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});

$('tr th:gt(0)').click(function() {

    var index = (this.cellIndex + 1);
    var cells = $('table tr > :nth-child(' + index + ')');
    cells.toggleClass('hide');

    if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>+</b>');
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('span').html('<b>-</b>');
    }

    if ($('table tr > th:not(.hide)').length)
        $('table').removeClass('hide');
    else
        $('table').addClass('hide');
     $('.btnAssociate').show();
});

 $('.btnAssociate').click(function()
    {


         $('.btnAssociate').hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('.btnAssociate').click(function () {
    $('table th,table td').removeClass('hide');
    $('.btnAssociate').hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/31/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [nifty way of doing it](http://jsfiddle.net/9QkVd/33/), you can **keep hiding the columns and bring them back in order** of the most recently clicked item.

Basically add an array to store the index values of the column you click on:

```
var indexVal = [];
```

And then on the **button click** function you write:

```
var cells = $('table tr > :nth-child(' + indexVal[indexVal.length-1] + ')');
cells.toggleClass('hide');
indexVal.pop();
if (!indexVal) $('.btnAssociate').hide();
```